# EXCEL VBA EVALUATE and REPLACE

Tags: excel, vba, replace, evaluate

I need to make Evaluate work for the Replace function.  The code is supposed to replace " -0700" with nothing.  The code is provided below along with data in column C:

```
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set rangc = sh.Range("c2:c10")
For Each area In rangc.Areas
  area.Value = Evaluate("IF(ROW(" & area.Address & ")," & Replace(area.Address, " -0700", "") & ")")
Next area
```

-This is the data in the sheet:

```
ColumnC(original data)
 -0700
sdfg -0700
how  -0700 saf
2016-10-16 10:13:41 -0700

ColumnC(After code is run)
-700
sdfg -0700
how  -0700 saf
10/16/2016 10:13
```

Why does the code did something to the first row (-700) but did not replace with "".  Also it did remove the " -700" in 4th row (10/16/2016 10:13).  But it did not work for 2nd and 3rd rows?  How do I make it work for strings or numbers?

I am trying to use similar code to replace partial string in another string very quickly.  I cannot accept using looping method because there are hundred thousands of rows.

Comment: *Why does the code did something to the first row (-700) but did not replace with "". Also it did remove the " -700" in 4th row (10/16/2016 10:13)* I think these removals were not the result of your code's replacement, but just some auto-formatting made by Excel.

Comment: you are probably right and I am asking for a solution for Evaluate that doesn't exist.

Comment: You are applying the `Replace` function to the address which will replace nothing. There might be some way using `SUBSTITUTE` but I think the `.Replace` method would be the go-to solution here.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop through the whole range. You can just use `.Replace` method which is pretty fast:

```
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set rangc = sh.Range("c2:c10")
rangc.Replace What:=" -0700", Replacement:=""
```